# Where can I find the source code for Singular (AngularJS for GWT)?

Tags: gwt

There was a talk at the [GWT.create 2015](http://gwtcreate.com/) conference about Singular.  I have tried to find the source code of the project on the web with no success.  Is this project still internal to Google? If so, are there any plans to open source it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Singular is still in the works (not even used inside Google) but will obviously be open sourced. You can follow the news at https://groups.google.com/d/forum/singular-contrib